# "This method makes it possible to reduce cost while improving reliability" is grammatically correct?

Tags: conjunctions

> 1. This method makes it possible to reduce the cost.
> 2. This method also makes it possible to improve the reliability.

I am trying to connect the two sentences above I created using **"while"** and I want to know which of the followings is correct:

> 1. This method makes it possible to reduce the cost while improving
>      the reliability.
> 2. This method makes it possible to reduce the cost while making it
>      possible to improve the reliability.

I think "This method makes it possible to reduce the cost and improve the reliability" is better, but I would like to know how to connect the sentences using "while".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both correct but number one would be better because it is more concise.

Using "and" instead of "while" doesn't really make a difference when I read it. (I am a native speaker). I guess you could say that using "while" is slightly more formal than "and" but you wouldn't get any weird looks if you used it during informal conversation.

Since you got all three sentences correct I'd say you sound just like a native and don't need any corrections on your use of "while".